# objective-c Custom UILabel not show text

Tags: ios, objective-c

i've made an custom UILabel class with xml;

```
#import "QDLabel.h"
#import "UIColor+HexString.h"
@interface QDLabel : QDView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel * label;

@end


@implementation QDLabel



- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        self.label.text = @"this is label";

        [self addSubview:self.label];

    }

    return self;

}
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self.label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

- (void)translateSpecailAttributes {

        [self translateText];

        [self translateTitleFont];
        [self translateTitleColor];
        [self translateTextAlign];
        [self translateTextLines];
//    });

}

- (void)translateText {
//    self.label.frame = self.bounds;
    NSString * string = self.getAttribute[@"text"];
    if (string.length > 0) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.label.text = string;
        });

    }
}

- (void)translateTitleColor {
    NSString * textColor = self.getAttribute[@"textColor"];
    if (textColor.length > 0) {
        self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        self.label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self.label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//        self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:textColor];
    }
}
- (void)translateTitleFont {
    NSString * string = self.getAttribute[@"fontSize"];
    if (string.length > 0) {
        self.label.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:string.floatValue ];
    }
}

- (void)translateTextAlign {
    NSString * string = self.getAttribute[@"textAlign"];
    NSTextAlignment textAlign = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"left"]) {
        textAlign = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    } else if ([string isEqualToString:@"right"]) {
        textAlign = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    } else if ([string isEqualToString:@"center"]) {
        textAlign = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    self.label.textAlignment = textAlign;
}

- (void)translateTextLines {
    NSString * string = self.getAttribute[@"lines"];
    if (string.length > 0) {
        self.label.numberOfLines = string.integerValue;
    }
}

and this QDView class

@implementation QDView

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)attribute {
    if (!_attribute) {
        _attribute = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return _attribute;
}

- (NSDictionary *)getAttribute {
    return self.attribute;
}

- (NSString *)getAttributeForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if (key) {
        return self.attribute[key];
    }
    return nil;
}
- (void)setAttribute:(NSString*)attr forKey:(NSString *)key {
    if (attr && key) {
        self.attribute[key] = attr;

    }
}

- (void)addChild:(QDView *)child {
    [self addSubview:child];
}

#pragma mark reload layoutsubview
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    //    DLog(@"qdview layout subviews");
    [self translateCommonAttributes];

    // 初始化子视图的个性化属性
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(translateSpecailAttributes)]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(translateSpecailAttributes)];
    }

}
}
```

when i print [self.view recursiveDescription], 
[the label's backgroudColor is normal. the label's text is 'this is label', but the text not show. i don't known the reason. can you help me?][1]

```
(lldb) po [self.view recursiveDescription]
<UIView: 0x13756aa00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x137569ce0>>
   | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x13756adb0; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x137512140>>
   | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x13756b7e0; frame = (0 568; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x137569bd0>>
   | <QDVerticalLayout: 0x1376a3040; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <CALayer: 0x1376a32d0>>
   |    | <UIScrollView: 0x138088c00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x13756a760>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1376a4bc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 49}>
   |    |    | <QDHorizontalLayout: 0x1376a4fd0; frame = (0 0; 320 49); layer = <CALayer: 0x1376a2420>>
   |    |    |    | <UIScrollView: 0x138092e00; frame = (0 0; 320 49); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1376a6090>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1376a03f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {260, 49}>
   |    |    |    |    | <QDLabel: 0x1376a6f30; frame = (60 8; 200 150); layer = <CALayer: 0x1376a7330>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1376a8080; frame = (0 0; 200 150); text = 'this is label'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x1376a85d0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x13757da30; frame = (314.5 39; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x13757d7a0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x13757cc90; frame = (310 43.5; 7 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x13757d180>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x13757ebe0; frame = (314.5 558; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x13757e950>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x13757e3b0; frame = (310 562.5; 7 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x13757e120>>
```